# Is there a way to record audio with React native and store it as a wave file?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, voice

when the user clicks the button, The app should start listening the audio and stop the recording when the user is  silent(say for 20 seconds after silence) , now store that audio file in a wave format(eg: test.wav) in react native ?

Comment: The beauty of RN is that there are LOADS of packages made for it. This is one for audio recording and I'm sure there are more: https://github.com/jsierles/react-native-audio

Comment: react-native-audio record and react-native-audio , is there any other thing?

Answer (score 1):

As you already know that there is no inbuilt feature to record audio in React Native, However you can always use third part Library/package. There are number of them available on NPM. Here is one of them [react native audio record](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-audio-record)

```js
import AudioRecord from 'react-native-audio-record';
 
const options = {
  sampleRate: 16000,  // default 44100
  channels: 1,        // 1 or 2, default 1
  bitsPerSample: 16,  // 8 or 16, default 16
  audioSource: 6,     // android only 
  wavFile: 'test.wav' // default 'audio.wav'
};
 
AudioRecord.init(options);

//Start Recording
AudioRecord.start();
 
 
//Stop Recording
AudioRecord.stop();
```

**Hope this help**

Answer (score 1):

If you are also interested in creating file from this recording in the user device, i recommend  using [react-native-audio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-audio)
i personally tried in android and it worked pretty smoothly, example of  code:

```
/* on top of component:*/
import {AudioRecorder, AudioUtils} from 'react-native-audio';
/*all your other imports*/
class Example extends Component {
     constructor(props) {
         super(props);
         this.AudioRecorder = AudioRecorder
       }
     startRecord(){
         let folder =  AudioUtils.DocumentDirectoryPath;
         let audioPath = folder +'/myFile.wav';
         let options=   { SampleRate: 22050,
            Channels: 1,
            AudioQuality: "Low",
            AudioEncoding: "wav",
            MeteringEnabled: true,};
        this.AudioRecorder.prepareRecordingAtPath(audioPath,options).then(
              ((success)=>{ this.AudioRecorder.startRecording((success)=>{
                                 }).catch((err)=>{})
             }).catch(err=>{})


       }

      stopRecord(){
          this.audioRecorder.stop()
       }

 }
```

you will probably also need user permission to use the device microphone, for this i recommend [react-native-permissions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-permissions)

Comment: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.AudioRecorder')

Comment: @NarendraSingh , maybe there is a problem with your import or  npm installation of the package, i recreated this error when import undefined object from react-native audio.

Comment: @NarendraSingh The library linked in this answer is no longer maintained. Has been updated in years. Probably not usable right now.